# @Async and @Transaction aspect order

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-aspects, spring-async

Using Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE / Spring Framework 5.1.4, I have an application with `@Async` and `@Transactional` annotations enabled through:

```java
@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

When running a method that is annotated with both, first the transaction is created and then the asynchronous execution starts. So, the actual method body is not executed inside the transaction.

```java
    @Transactional
    @Async
    public void myAsyncMethod() {
        // asynchronous database stuff
    }
```

How can I configure spring / the aspects to actually execute in an order that makes sense, e.g. start the transaction on the new thread?

On a side note, with the older Spring Boot 1.5.17 / Spring Framework 4.3.20 it actually worked.

Demo: https://github.com/jaarts/spring-asynctransaction-demo

Comment: Hint, the `@Enable` annotations have an `order` attribute.

Comment: Tnx, I tried that, but it had no effect.

Comment: YOu are using AspectJ mode so you have either load or compile time weaving enabled. Have you tried simply switching the orde r of the `@Transactional`and `@Async` annotations? Apparently when using AspectJ mode (instead of proxies) it follows the order of the annotations as declared on the class (which from a weaving pov I find quite logical).

Comment: I'm indeed using compile time weaving. Changing the order of the annotations on the method also had no effect. I'm guessing it has to do with the order in which the aspects are presented to the weaver.

Comment: Have you included them in the `aop.xml` needed for the weaving? You should be able to control the order there. Although they are in the order async then transaction when looking at the `aop.xml` shipped with Spring.

Comment: I'm not using any custom `aop.xml`. From what I understand, this file is for load-time weaving only.

Comment: Compile time as well to determine which aspects to apply. Spring ships with an `aop.xml` but that ordering is async before tx.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 5 Async advice is always execited first. See AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

```
public AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    setBeforeExistingAdvisors(true);
}
```

After that on superclass in postProcessAfterInitialization when advisors aplies code executes

```
if (this.beforeExistingAdvisors) {
   advised.addAdvisor(0, this.advisor);
}
```

On @EnableTransactionManagement#order javadoc says

> Indicate the ordering of the execution of the transaction advisor

but on @EnableAsync

> Indicate the order in which the AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **aspectj with compile time weaving (ctw)** for me the only solution was to add an Aspect and use **DeclarePrecedence** like this:

```
package org.example.config;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;
   
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence(
  "org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect" 
  + "," + 
  "org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"
)
public class AspectOrdering {}
```